# Linq Query not returning value from database field

Tags: c#, linq

I literally have no idea why this isn't querying the way I expect it to query, I am however new to programming but in my head it seems right.

I am using **this.Context.User.Identity.Name** to return the logged in user however it returns an email not the username. Here is the script in it's context.

```
@Html.ActionLink("My Account", "Users", new { id = this.Context.User.Identity.Name  },     false) @: | @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Users")
```

from this I want the url to look like **website/Users/Username** hence wanting to get username instead of email.

The query:

```
Project1.Models.DBContext db = new Project1.Models.DBContext();
//save u.Username in var user where u.Email == user_logged_in_email

var user = from u in db.Users
           where u.Email == this.Context.User.Identity.Name
           select u.Username;
```

I was hoping that the linq query would find the row that contained the email address and then pull the Username out and store it in var user. what it really equals is System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enumerate that query to get the user:

```
var user = (from u in db.Users
           where u.Email == this.Context.User.Identity.Name
           select u.Username).SingleOrDefault();
//SingleOrDefault will return null if no user is found, so you need to check for that before operating upon the user object.
```

Comment: This works perfectly. **I would never have thought to do that**. What is the reason behind Enumerating? What does it do and why is it needed?

Comment: The linq has no way of knowing whether your `where` clause will return a single result or not, so a `from-where-select always` returns a collection (actually, it returns a queryable that could return a collection). `SingleOrDefault()` will return the only element of that collection, and throw an error if there is more than one element. `FirstOrDefault` does a similar thing but without the exception.

Comment: Specifically, LINQ has no way of knowing that you didn't just want to create a query, so it built you a query. The results of that query can be pulled out by Enumerating (executing) that query. The query does not get run until you call a method such as ToList, Single(), SingleOrDefault() on it.

Comment: Ahh I didn't realise linq created a list even though i was trying to target a single. I guess that comes from experience. Thanks

Comment: Correct. A where clause will return you an IEnumerable<T> based on your query. It's up to you as the programmer to intelligently decide whether your query is going to return you a single item or not.